# Running a method while Waiting for input

Tags: java

I have an application in which a JOptionPane is called.
How can I continuously run a method until the yes on the JOption Pane has been selected?

```
move = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, game + "\n" + "Your Move " + game.inputPrompt() + " ?");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Put your processing in a separate thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 1):

Threading. Create a new thread to do whatever you want until move gets set.

Answer (score 1):

You should [use threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) to have several portions of code executing in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't want to continuously run a method (that would peg your CPU). Do you mean run it in parallel while waiting for the user input? If then you can start a new thread.

Have a look at the Runnable interface

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html